# Symfony 3.4 Command vs oracle wallet ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine

I have a Symfony 3.4 application connected to an Oracle DB via a Wallet, so the configuration of the DB username and password are outside the app and of my control.

To let the application to work with this specific configuration I added in the config.yml, the parameter:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                ...
                session_mode: !php/const OCI_CRED_EXT 
                ...
```

The application works without any problem.

I have a sync function that connect to different DBs and sync some data.
The sync function can be run manually within the application UI and it works.

I wrote a console command to run in a cron job that instantiate the same set of classes used manually by the application but I got the error in object when I execute the command via terminal.

The exact error is:

```
In AbstractOracleDriver.php line 57:

  An exception occurred in driver: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified  


In OCI8Exception.php line 16:

  ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

The same error occurs when testing the db connection with the console:

```
#php .\bin\console  doctrine:query:sql "select sysdate,current_date from dual"
```

So, it seams that the console command in some way ignore that the oracle connection i made through a wallet and looks for **servicename** parameter  which is, obviously, empty resulting in a TNS error.

Do someone have some suggestion on how to fix the issue?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Try `sessionMode`  instead of session_mode

Comment: Thanks SilvioQ for your reply, but nothing changes.